# accountEnabled filter no longer supported on graph query

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We had a user query hitting the `/beta` endpoint that has been working for the last few months, and sometime over the last few days it has stopped working and returns an Authorization_RequestDenied error.

Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I have it narrowed down to the use of the `accountEnabled eq true` filter clause. If I remove this filter clause the query works.

Full query is:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=(startswith(givenName,%27sim%27)%20or%20startswith(surname,%27sim%27)%20or%20startswith(displayName,%27sim%27))%20and%20accountEnabled%20eq%20true&$select=id,userPrincipalName,givenName,surname,displayName,mail,userType`

I've done a quick search and have not found anything in the changelog.

The exact error is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d04d57d3-6e43-4e73-860a-ef721636929b",
            "date": "2018-05-12T20:02:57"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get from [List user API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list).

> Important: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

I can't reproduce it with your supplied full query on my side. It works correctly on my side.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just double checked and problem is still happening on my end - even with basic filter expression of: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=(accountEnabled eq true)

Comment: As a matter of interest is the graph explorer admin consented in your organizations AD? Thanks Donal

Comment: I test it with global admin.

Comment: If you still reproduce the issue, you could create a [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get the deep help from microsoft

Comment: I too can log in as global admin and change the permissions to include User.Read.All and the query will work. However this permission requires admin consent for non admin users so that solution is not a viable option. Will follow up with MS

Comment: In order to read this property for other users, you need `User.Read.All` which, as you noted, _will_ require Admin Consent.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur was this a silent "bug" fix that went in as accountEnabled worked fine as a query filter up to 2 weeks ago with just User.Read? When it worked in a filter expression, I was never able to get to property value back in the result set.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. You shouldn't be able to filter against properties you don't have permission to read. Otherwise you could easily just reverse engineer the value using filters and sidestep security.